# New system build off/on issue

Tags: windows-7, power, computer-building, reset

I just built a new system with the following specs. The problem I'm having is when I do a reset or turn the computer on it exhibits behaviors I think are not normal but I'm not sure since its a UEFI motherboard and this is the first system build in ten years for me.

```
Rampage IV Extreme x79
Intel i7-4820K @3.7GHz
Patriot Viper III DDR3 1600MHz (PC3-12800) PV38G160C9K
Samsung 840 Pro 256Gb SSD
Corsair Professional Series Gold AX1200 PSU
Corsair H75 liquid cooling
Windows 7 Ultimate x64
```

If I'm in the the bios and choose "save & reset", press ctrl+alt+del before I'm in the OS, press the reset button on the chassis, or if I'm in windows and tell it to restart it's a complete crap shoot as to what will happen. Here are some examples:

```
Reset -> powers itself off -> stays off.
Reset -> powers itself off -> waits 4 seconds -> turns on -> boots normally.
Reset -> powers itself off -> waits 4 seconds -> turns on -> hangs with various LED codes (codes are not consistent).
Reset -> powers itself off -> waits 4 seconds -> turns on -> powers itself off -> stays off.
Reset -> powers itself off -> waits 4 seconds -> turns on -> powers itself off -> waits 4 seconds -> turns on -> boots normally.
```

And here are some initial power on examples:

```
Power On -> powers itself off -> stays off.
Power On -> powers itself off -> waits 4 seconds -> powers itself on -> boots normally.
```

So the question is this normal for a UEFI board to cycle the power on and off like this during a initial power on or a reset?

Comment: It sounds like it's running a power test before it boots, but that should only happen if the computer loses power suddenly or shuts down abnormally. It could be a power setting in the BIOS. Have you overclocked the CPU at all?

Comment: Nope, no overclocking. I've updated to the uefi to latest and reset the entire configuration to default. Memtested and memory passed. Still seeing odd power on/off cycles during resets that make no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bad motherboard. Returned it and got a Rampage IV Extreme Black Edition board and I don't have this issue anymore.